# Powershell C# get PDF Charactor Location

Tags: c#, powershell, pdf, text, itext

Can someone tell me if there is a way to get each characters location in X,Y coordinates from a PDF.
i appreciate that it may not be XY i just need a way to identify where a text character is on a page.
the characters are not raster, so i don't need to recognise them.
i have started with this.

```
$Path = "C:\temp\test.pdf"

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $Path

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
{
$text = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader,$page).Split([char]0x000A)
}

$reader.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar at all with PowerShell, but you can do it like this in C#. FYI you will either need iTextSharp 5.5.10 or iText 7.0.1 for .NET to get this to run.

```
void Run()
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("/path/to/input.pdf");

    var s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(new Local()));
}

private class Local : LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocationStrategy
    {

    public LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocation CreateLocation(TextRenderInfo renderInfo, LineSegment baseline)
    {
        // you need the info per character, so iterate all characters per TextRenderInfo
        foreach (TextRenderInfo tr in renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
        {
            LineSegment bl = tr.GetBaseline();
            // do something with the info
            Console.WriteLine(tr.GetText() + " @ (" + bl.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I1] + ", " + bl.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2] + ")");
        }
        return new LocationTextExtractionStrategy.TextChunkLocationDefaultImp(baseline.GetStartPoint(), baseline.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on **blagae** answer, here is a powershell script that will basically run his C# code. I didn't find an easy way to use LocationTextExtractionStrategy directly in powershell. You will need iTextSharp 5.5.10 as it is the first public version to expose LocationTextExtractionStrategy.

```
$Source = @"
        using System;
        using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
        using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

        public class PdfHelper
        {
            public static void Run(string filePath)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
                for(var page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(new Local()));
                }
            }
        }

        class Local : LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocationStrategy
        {
            public LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocation CreateLocation(TextRenderInfo renderInfo, LineSegment baseline)
            {
                // you need the info per character, so iterate all characters per TextRenderInfo
                foreach (TextRenderInfo tr in renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
                {
                    LineSegment bl = tr.GetBaseline();
                    // do something with the info
                    Console.WriteLine(tr.GetText() + " @ (" + bl.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I1] + ", " + bl.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2] + ")");
                }
                return new LocationTextExtractionStrategy.TextChunkLocationDefaultImp(baseline.GetStartPoint(), baseline.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth());
            }
        }
"@ 

$DLLPath = "$PSScriptRoot\iTextSharp.dll"
Add-Type -Path $DLLPath
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $DLLPath -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

$Path = "C:\temp\test.pdf"
[PdfHelper]::Run($Path)
```